# BigQuery loading data from json export of sql data

Tags: sql, json, database, google-bigquery, sql-server-2016

BigQuery can load data from a json but the requirement is that one JSON object, including any nested/repeated fields, **must appear on each line**.

Does anyone know how to export data from a sql server 2016 database using FOR JSON so that the file can be load by BigQuery (i.e json new line delimited)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer but I have found a more elegant solution that only requires sql.  Using the FOR JSON clause to wrap the individual records and then using SQL Server Data Export to pipe the results to a file.

SELECT 
    (
        SELECT  E.EmployeeID,
                E.FirstName 
        FROM    dbo.Employees E
        WHERE   E.EmployeeID = EE.EmployeeID
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )  X
FROM   dbo.Employees EE

Answer (score 0):

Create formatting script yourself, any language with file reads, regexps & string replace would be good for it (and it's virtually no one without all that nowadays).

It's gonna take hour or two or three - already fits into the period you've been waiting for response. :-)